# In-text hyperlinks shown by Internet Explorer without the following space. What can be the reason? YUI?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've a problem which is most likely some ugly CSS mistake, but I just can't spot the solution (and a few changes I tried did not help).

Some of in-text hyperlinks (not all!) are shown by Internet Explorer without the following space.

[here is the example](http://blog.mekk.waw.pl/archives/28-Picking-the-games-to-watch.html)

See the link *WatchBot* just below the *Rationale* title (and a few similar links deeper in the article). Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Konqueror - all display it properly: **WatchBot** *can*. IE (6.0 but IIRC also 7.0) displays it as **WatchBot***can*.

I am using Yui-reset and yui-base. Is it possible that those libraries cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: my page was spoiled by the text-link-ads script (which, in fact I activated on English blog by mistake - this is script by adkontekst.wp.pl, Polish firm). After disabling it everything is OK.

Thanks for everybody who pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a script running on, and altering, the content in any way? I say this because the page loads normally initially, but looks as though it undergos some modification later in the loading lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't spotted this and maybe this is a point.

Answer (score 1):

If you think reset or base are making this happen try removing them one at a time - I haven't had any experience of this error before however (I usually use the full whack: Reset, Grids, Base and Fonts).

What I did notice however is that the first WatchBot link of the page is simply this:

```
<p>Have you ever been curious how is 
<a href="http://mekk.waw.pl/mk/watchbot/index">WatchBot</a>
picking the games to observe and save? Here is the explanation.</p>
```

Where as the second link looks like this:

```
<span>Due to the FICS limitations </span>
<a href="http://mekk.waw.pl/mk/watchbot/index">WatchBot</a><span> can
```

I have no idea what that second span is doing there - might be something to check up on. (It validated fine however - so there's definitely an closing span somewhere).

Comment: Hmmm. I checked page sources before posting the question, and I did not see those <span>'s then. Thanks for pointing that you got them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a good place to start would be to but a space after the anchor but before the span, rather than right after the span start tag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable pageTracker? It seems to be the only script on your page, and it looks fine to me in its static form.

EDIT: I wondered what span Ross was talking about - I did not see any. I viewed the source. I just learned that Firefox allows to see both source and generated source (Toos/Web Developer/View Source). Sure enough, generated source has additional span inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Current state of the things: as steve_c spotted first, and buti-oxa confirmed, it looks like the layout is being spoiled by javascript (and as Ross noted, some extra spans are injected). Thank you all, I missed it.

I am to make experiments and selectively disable those scripts (analytics and google ads) to check whether it helps (my current bet is that maybe I have some HTML error or naming conflict)